# Call to a member function on a non object error in mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding a Follow profile function to my page.

I have a Follow button which changes to Unfollow if there is a row in database containing profile ID and session ID. If the person clicks on Unfollow I get an error saying:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in blah blah line 20

This is the code I'm running:

```
function isFollow($mysqli){
if(isset($_POST['isFollow']))
    {
        $fed_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fed_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $fing_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fing_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $isFollow = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'isFollow', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if($isFollow==0)
        {
            $fing_time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO follower (fed_user, fing_user, date_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('iii', $fed_id, $fing_id, $fing_time);
            if($insert_stmt->execute())
            {
                header("Location:../?profile=".$fed_id."");
            }
        }elseif($isFollow==1)
        {
            $delete_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM follower WHERE fed_id = ? AND fing_id = ?");
            $delete_stmt->bind_param('ii', $fed_id, $fing_id);
            if($delete_stmt->execute())
            {
                header("Location:../?profile=".$fed_id."");
            }
        }
}else
{
    die("Error!");
}
}
```

The first part of the code works. It adds in mysql. It just won't delete from it.

Line 20 is

```
$delete_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM follower WHERE fed_id = ? AND fing_id = ?");
```

Please note it works all untill this part:

```
elseif($isFollow==1)
    {
        $delete_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM follower WHERE fed_id = ? AND fing_id = ?");
        $delete_stmt->bind_param('ii', $fed_id, $fing_id);
        if($delete_stmt->execute())
        {
            header("Location:../?profile=".$fed_id."");
        }
    }
```

Comment: From documentation , *they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not allowed to compare marker with NULL by ? IS NULL too. In general, parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to a failure in prepare. Try printing the error with

```
trigger_error( $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR );
```

after line 20 and check what went wrong.

You may also want to check of what type and value *$delete_stmt* is using

```
print_r( $delete_stmt );
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks! trigger_error returned it cannot recognize one of the ID's as it was set as user and not ID.